# predicting ROI for a recommendation system (campaign)

Tags: prediction, recommendation-engine

Here are my dataframes columns:
main dataframe:pk_partition', 'pk_cid', 'loans', 'mortgage', 'funds', 'securities',
'long_term_deposit', 'credit_card', 'payroll',
'payroll_pension_unknown', 'payroll_account', 'emc_account',
'debit_card', 'em_account_p', 'em_account', 'entry_date',
'active_customer', 'segment', 'region_code', 'deceased',
'New Monthly Subscribers', 'prev_partition', 'Loyal Customer',
'New Customer', 'Regular Customer', 'Entry_Channel_KAT',
'Entry_Channel_KFC', 'Entry_Channel_KHE', 'Entry_Channel_KHK',
'Entry_Channel_KHQ', 'Entry_Channel_Others', 'Entry_Channel_Unknown',
'01 - TOP', '02 - PARTICULARES', '03 - UNIVERSITARIO',
'Unknown Segment', 'region_10', 'region_11', 'region_12', 'region_13',
'region_14', 'region_15', 'region_18', 'region_2', 'region_21',
'region_28', 'region_29', 'region_3', 'region_30', 'region_33',
'region_35', 'region_36', 'region_37', 'region_39', 'region_41',
'region_45', 'region_46', 'region_47', 'region_50', 'region_6',
'region_7', 'region_8', 'region_Others', 'female', 'age_group_Adult',
'age_group_Middle-Aged', 'age_group_Senior', 'age_group_Young Adult',
'Unknown_salary', 'high_salary', 'low_salary', 'medium_salary',
'short_term_deposit', 'pension']
created timeseries unsupervised dataframe monthly aggreagated:
Index(['pk_partition', 'deceased', 'Total_Subscribers', 'Active_Customers',
'New Monthly Subscribers', 'Unsubscribed', 'Loyal Customer',
'New Customer', 'Regular Customer', 'Entry_Channel_KAT',
'Entry_Channel_KFC', 'Entry_Channel_KHE', 'Entry_Channel_KHK',
'Entry_Channel_KHQ', 'Entry_Channel_Others', 'Entry_Channel_Unknown',
'02 - PARTICULARES', '03 - UNIVERSITARIO', 'Unknown Segment',
'01 - TOP', 'region_11', 'region_15', 'region_28', 'region_30',
'region_41', 'region_46', 'region_8', 'region_Others', 'female',
'age_group_Senior', 'age_group_Middle-Aged', 'age_group_Adult',
'age_group_Young Adult', 'medium_salary', 'Unknown_salary',
'high_salary', 'low_salary', 'Total_Short_Term_Deposit', 'loans',
'mortgages', 'funds', 'securities', 'credit_card', 'debit_card',
'long_term_deposit', 'payroll', 'pension', 'payroll_pension_unknown',
'payroll_account', 'em_account', 'em_account_p', 'emc_account'],
dtype='object')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry it seems deleted